# jspdf-autotable - didParseCell not working

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have used jspdf-autotable and previously it was working. But I don't know why, suddenly after a month it is not working. Previously, in the didParseCell HookData, I was getting the value of the tdElement. But now I don't find any value. Has the configuration of HookData changed in the new release ? Here is my code -

**app.component.ts**

```
capture() {

    var doc = new jspdf('l', 'pt', 'a4');

    var cols = [{ title: 'Id', dataKey: 'id' },
    { title: 'Source-Field Resolved Path', dataKey: 'sourceName' }, { title: 'Source Field Technical Name', dataKey: 'sfieldName' },
    { title: 'Source Data Type', dataKey: 'sdataType' }, { title: 'Target Field Resolved Path', dataKey: 'targetName' },
    { title: 'Target Field Technical Name', dataKey: 'tfieldName' }, { title: 'Target Data Type', dataKey: 'tdataType' }, { title: 'Condition', dataKey: 'urgencyName' },
    { title: 'Description', dataKey: 'descriptionName' }, { title: 'Source Field Row No.', dataKey: 'directRowNo' },
    { title: 'Source Field Path', dataKey: 'sourceFieldPath' }, { title: 'Source Field Name', dataKey: 'sourceFieldName' },
    { title: 'Data Type Verified', dataKey: 'datatypeVerified' }]

    var tableData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.responseData.length; i++) {
      tableData.push({
        'id': this.responseData[i].id, 'sourceName': this.responseData[i].sourceName, 'sfieldName': this.responseData[i].sfieldName, 'sdataType': this.responseData[i].sdataType,
        'targetName': this.responseData[i].targetName, 'tfieldName': this.responseData[i].tfieldName, 'tdataType': this.responseData[i].tdataType, 'urgencyName': this.responseData[i].urgencyName,
        'descriptionName': this.responseData[i].descriptionName, 'directRowNo': this.responseData[i].directRowNo, 'sourceFieldPath': this.responseData[i].sourceFieldPath,
        'sourceFieldName': this.responseData[i].sourceFieldName, 'datatypeVerified': this.responseData[i].datatypeVerified, 'backgroundColor': this.responseData[i].backgroundColor
      })
    }
    doc.autoTable(cols, tableData, {


        didParseCell: function (HookData ){


        console.log("HookData = ", HookData)


        var tdElement;


        tdElement = HookData.row.raw.backgroundColor
          ;
        console.log("tdElement = ", tdElement)
        if (tdElement == false && HookData.column.raw.dataKey == "datatypeVerified") {

          HookData.cell.styles.fontStyle = 'bold';
          HookData.cell.styles.textColor = [255, 0, 0]
        }


      }

    })


    document.getElementById('obj').dataset.data = 
    doc.output("datauristring");


    var blob = doc.output("blob");
    window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));

  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:30px" (click) = "capture()" id="capture" >Capture</button>

<object id="obj"  [attr.data]  type="application/pdf"> </object>
```

Comment: can you provide the output of console.log(HookData)

Comment: Your initailization seems outdated. `doc.autoTable(columns, data, options)` is now `doc.autoTable({head: ..., body: ... foot: ..., columns: ..., ...})`. Which version are u using? Maybe u should take a look at the changelog https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/releases/tag/v3.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing your autotable with columns and rows from javascript. Therefore autoTable is not connected to any html table. The raw property of hook data (hookData.row.raw) is only an instance of tr element when autoTable is initialized with the `html` option.

Verified now that hookData.row.raw is an instance of tr element in the latest version,

```
doc.autoTable({html: '.table', didDrawCell: data => {
    console.log(data.row.raw) // Instance of <tr> element
}});
```